# Theme Preloader for speed optimization in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, performance, wp-rocket

I have a WordPress website. And for speed optimization, I used WP Rocket. I used a preloader from theme options. The site took a long time to load for the first time when I used it. But, after the first time, the site loads fast. I keep the site loader that comes with the theme options. How can I improve the loading time for the first time using the preloader?